# Eslint cannot read config file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am setting up my first eslint. For some reason in other computers it works except on mine ..

**Im using VScode**

As soon as I open my editor I get the following message:
Cannot read config file: 

`/Users/user/Documents/repos/project/C:/mydirectory/.eslintrc.json Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
Source: ESLint (Extension)`

`.eslintrc.json` is on my root directory.

This is my config file:

```js
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "jest": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "quote-props": [2, "as-needed"],
      "comma-dangle": "error",
      "no-console": ["warn", { "allow": ["warn", "error"] }],
      "no-debugger": "error",
      "react/prop-types": 0,
      "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", { "devDependencies": true }],
      "object-curly-newline": ["error", { "multiline": true }],
      "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
      "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": 0,
      "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0,
      "no-await-in-loop": 0,
      "no-unused-expressions": ["error", { "allowShortCircuit": true, "allowTernary": true }],
      "arrow-parens": ["error", "as-needed"],
      "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }],
      "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
      "react/no-find-dom-node": 0,
      "no-shadow": 0,
      "max-len": 0,
      "consistent-return": 0,
      "no-plusplus": 0,
      "spaced-comment": 0,
      "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0,
      "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
      "indent": ["error", 4],
      "react/jsx-indent": ["error", 4],
      "react/jsx-indent-props": ["error", 4]
    }
  }
```

This is my `package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@internal/project": "latest",
    "@rematch/core": "^0.6.0",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.1",
    "ag-grid-react": "^18.1.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.50.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "jest": "^23.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "promise": "^8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-apollo": "^2.1.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-jss": "^8.6.1",
    "react-loadable": "^5.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js --ext .jsx src",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node",
      "mjs"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0"
  }
}
```

I've tried several things, including: adding `{ "root": true }`, opening from project, installing/uninstalling `eslint` extension

Comment: It looks like the path your editor is expecting is wrong. What is the editor you are using, and in what way have you configured it?

Comment: Your path doesn't look quite right, I don't think it should have `C:` in there

Comment: What do you mean by "in your root directory"? In any case, sounds like your editor config is wrong, but you don't say anything about what editor you're using, so *shrug*. In general they'll look for .eslint in the directory you open it from.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am using VsCode, I just updated my post. @DaveNewton. In my `settings.json` my `{ eslint.options}` is set to an empty object. Should it be configured there?

Comment: @SteveVaughan, can you elaborate on what you mean by how I configured it?

Comment: @rowmna Sure, so in VSCode, you may well need to provide it a path to the config file. The error you have is very likely caused by using the default setup mentioned here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Try and setting that to the absolute path to your config file

Comment: @SteveVaughan that worked, thanks! If you want you can add a post and i'll give you an upvote :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this relates to VSCode, the configuration file should be setup with a path to your config. See the guide [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)

The eslintOptions.configFile should be an absolute path to your config file.

Comment: I work on my project mostly in WebStorm and this problem appears to have occurred after working on it a bit in VSCode -- it may have also made a difference that I opened one of the subfolders and not the project's root folder. I can't figure out how to fix it and I don't see `eslintOptions` even in the vscode settings json. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

Just restarting the ESlint server fixed the problem for me.

Comment: You can restart the ESLint Server in VS Code with `Ctrl + P` --> ESLint: Restart ESLint Server

Comment: @Rubanov I think `Ctrl + Shift + P` would be the correct shortcut though. (`Cmd + Shift + P` on macOS)

Comment: you are correct. It's `Ctrl + Shift + P`

Comment: Very underrated answer.

Comment: I totally agree. But it worked in my case unfortunately.